# Why can't I see which commit deleted my file?

Tags: git

I want to revert a delete commit, but I can't dig it out of the history.

```
$ ls -l src/frontend/app/controllers/firm-news.js
ls: src/frontend/app/controllers/firm-news.js: No such file or directory
$ git log --diff-filter=D --all --full-history -- src/frontend/app/controllers/firm-news.js
$ git log --all --full-history -- src/frontend/app/controllers/firm-news.js

commit 0bc1e523eb58f98493f1ec23b681edf2cfc9eceb
Merge: 0f6f739 5d5ef9d
Author: Kit Sunde <kitsunde@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 17 17:35:48 2018 +0800

    Merge branch 'staging' into production

[..]
```

There's a series of merges, but if I switch to the staging branch, the file exists there also without a delete commit. How do I figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried "git reflog -g"?

Comment: You may have to trace back to the parent(s) where the commit you want took place.  That is to say, a merge commit in Git normally has two parents.

Comment: add `-m` to `git log --diff-filter=D --all --full-history -- src/frontend/app/controllers/firm-news.js` as it was probably deleted by a merge commit, which `git log` simply isn't showing.